# Molde de tipo en Delphi

Tags: poo, delphi, casting

Necesito aclararme en el tema de moldes de tipo en Delphi.

He escrito un ejemplo con dos clases, `TClassA` y `TClassB`. `TClassB` hereda de `TClassA`. El código es el siguiente:

```
program TEST;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}


uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TClassA = class(TObject)
  public
    Member1:Integer;
    constructor Create();
    function ToString():String; override;
  end;

type
  TClassB = class(TClassA)
  public
    Member2:Integer;
    constructor Create();
    function ToString():String; override;
    function MyToString():String;
  end;

{ TClassA }

constructor TClassA.Create;
begin
  Member1 := 0;
end;

function TClassA.ToString: String;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(Member1);
end;

{ TClassB }

constructor TClassB.Create;
begin
  Member1 := 0;
  Member2 := 10;
end;

function TClassB.MyToString: String;
begin
  Result := Format('My Values is: %u AND %u',[Member1,Member2]);
end;

function TClassB.ToString: String;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(Member1) + ' - ' + IntToStr(Member2);
end;


procedure ShowInstances();
var
  a: TClassA;
  b: TClassB;
begin
  a := TClassA.Create;
  b := TClassB(a); // Casting (B and A point to the same Memory Address)
  b.Member1 := 5;
  b.Member2 := 150; // why no error? (1)

  Writeln(Format('ToString: a = %s, a = %s',[a.ToString,b.ToString])); // (2)
  Writeln(Format('Class Name: a=%s, b=%s',[a.ClassName,b.ClassName])); // (3)
  Writeln(Format('Address: a=%p, b=%p',[@a,@b])); // (4)
  Writeln(b.MyToString); // why no error? (5)

  readln;
end;

begin
  try
    ShowInstances;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

La salida del programa es:

```
ToString: a = 5, a = 5
Class Name: a=TClassA, b=TClassA
Address: a=0012FF44, b=0012FF40
My Values is: 5 AND 150
```

Y mis dudas son:

1. ¿Cuál es la dirección de `Member2`? ¿Es este un posible *Access Violation*?
2. ¿El método `ToString` apunta a la misma dirección?
3. ¿Por qué `a` y `b` tienen el mismo nombre de clase?
4. ¿Son `a` y `b` dos variables diferentes?
5. Si `b` es de tipo `TClassA`, por qué puedo utilizar el método `MyToString` sobre ella?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás aplicando un *hard type cast* sobre la variable. Cuándo haces eso, le estás diciendo al compilador que sabes lo que haces, y el compilador *confía* en ti.

Vamos pregunta por pregunta:

> 1. ¿Cuál es la dirección de Member2? ¿Es este un posible Access Violation?

Cuándo asignas un valor a un miembro de una clase, la definición de clase de la variable es utilizada por el compilador para calcular el *corrimiento* (*offset*) de dicho miembro en la memoria, así que si tienes una declaración de clase como esta:

```
type
  TMyClass = class(TObject)
    Member1: Integer; //4 bytes
    Member2: Integer; //4 bytes
  end;
```

La representación en memoria de una instancia de esta clase luce algo así:

```
referencia (puntero) al objeto
|
|
-------------> [VMT][Member1][Member2][Monitor]
corrimiento     0    4        8         12
```

Cuando escribes una sentencia como esta:

```
MyObject.Member2 := 20;
```

El compilador utiliza este *mapa* de la clase para calcular la dirección de memoria a la cual aplicar la asignación. En este caso, el compilador *traducirá* la asignación en el equivalente a:

```
PInteger(Cardinal(MyObject) + 8)^ := 20;
```

Así que, la asignación que realizas tiene éxito solo por la manera en que el *memory manager* default trabaja. Un *Access Violation* se origina en el sistema operativo, cuándo tratas de acceder una dirección de memoria que no ha sido asignada a tu programa. En este caso, tu programa ha reservado más de la memoria mínima requerida al sistema operativo. En mi opinión, cuándo no obtienes un *Access Violation* tu, en realidad, no tienes suerte, ya que la memoria de tu programa ha sido corrompida silenciosamente. Cualquier otra variable que pudiera residir en dicha dirección habrá cambiado de valor (o meta datos), y esto resultará en un comportamiento indeterminado.

> 2. ¿El método ToString apunta a la misma dirección?

Dado que el método `ToString()` es virtual, la dirección de dicho método es almacenada en la *tabla de métodos virtuales* ([VMT](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Internal_Data_Formats#Class_Types), por sus siglas en inglés) y la llamada es determinada en tiempo de corrida. Te recomiendo leer (en inglés) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679022/what-data-does-a-tobject-contain y el capítulo del libro: [The Delphi Object Model](http://oreilly.com/catalog/delphi/chapter/ch02.html).

> 3. ¿Por qué a y b tienen el mismo nombre de clase?

En tiempo de ejecución, el nombre de clase también es parte de los meta-datos de un objeto. El hecho de que estés aplicando el molde incorrecto a un objeto, no cambia el objeto en si mismo.

¿Son a y b dos variables diferentes?

Claro que si, tu mismo las has declarado, dale una mirada a tu código:

```
var
  a: TClassA;
  b: TClassB;
```

Bien, son dos variables diferentes. En Delphi, las variables a objetos son, en realidad, punteros, así que luego de algunas líneas de código, ambas apuntan a la misma dirección, pero eso es otra cosa.

> 5. Si b es de tipo TClassA, por qué puedo utilizar el método MyToString sobre ella?

Porque tu le estás diciendo al compilador que eso está bien, y cómo ya he dicho antes, el compilador *confía en ti*. Calificaría esto que has hecho como *oscuro*, pero Delphi es también un lenguaje de bajo nivel en dónde se te permite hacer muchas cosas locas, si quieres (y sabes lo que haces), pero:

## Juega seguro

Si quieres (y seguramente lo quieres la mayor parte del tiempo) estar del lado seguro, no apliques moldes de tipo como estos en tu código. Utiliza el [operador **as**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Class_References#The_as_Operator) (la traducción es mía):

> El operador **as** realiza moldes de tipo verificados. La expresión
>
> *object* **as** *class*
>
> retorna una referencia al mismo objeto *object*, pero con el tipo dado por *class*. En tiempo de corrida, el objeto debe ser una instancia de la clase *class*, uno de sus descendientes, o `nil`. Si no lo es, se eleva una excepción. Si el tipo con el que fue declarado *object* no está relacionado con *class* –es decir, si los tipos son distintos y uno no es el ancestro del otro– se produce un error en tiempo de compilación.

Así que, con el operador `as`, estás seguro, tanto en tiempo de compilación como en tiempo de corrida.

Cambia tu código a algo como esto:

```
procedure ShowInstance(A: TClassA);
var
  b: TClassB;
begin
  b := A as TClassB; //excepción al ejecutarse, el resto del código
                     //compilado no se ejecutará si a no es de tipo
                     //TClassB
  b.Member1 := 5;
  b.Member2 := 150; 

  Writeln(Format('ToString: a = %s, a = %s',[a.ToString,b.ToString])); 
  Writeln(Format('Class Name: a=%s, b=%s',[a.ClassName,b.ClassName])); 
  Writeln(Format('Address: a=%p, b=%p',[@a,@b])); 
  Writeln(b.MyToString); 

  readln;
end;

procedure ShowInstances();
begin
  ShowInstance(TClassB.Create); //éxito
  ShowInstance(TClassA.Create); //fallo en tiempo de corrida
                                //la memoria no se ha corrompido
end;
```

Con información de [Delphi Type Casting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14626862/255257)